Turn off logging for Actuator endpoints in Spring Boot
In my application.properties I have configured the logging as follows:
logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE

This is by intention and should stay as it is. When an Actuator endpoint (such as /actuator/health) is called there are many entries written to the logs:
LOCAL INFO  [io-18080-exec-3,] AccessLogFilter                          : servletRequest-Attribute: null
LOCAL INFO  [io-18080-exec-3,] AccessLogFilter                          : Request-Uri: /actuator/health
LOCAL INFO  [io-18080-exec-3,] AccessLogFilter                          : servletRequest: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4783a4a1
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] DispatcherServlet                        : GET "/actuator/health", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor       : Read "application/vnd.vendor-onboarding.v1+json;charset=UTF-8" to [{}]
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] HandlerMethod                            : Arguments: [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4783a4a1, {}]
LOCAL DEBUG [io-18080-exec-3,] HttpEntityMethodProcessor                : Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] HttpEntityMethodProcessor                : Writing [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth@782d7d50]
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] RequestMappingHandlerAdapter             : Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
LOCAL TRACE [io-18080-exec-3,] DispatcherServlet                        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
LOCAL DEBUG [io-18080-exec-3,] DispatcherServlet                        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}

How can I prevent this? I would like to turn off logging for specific endpoints.
